# How to access a variable in mumtiple cpp files contain main section in each file?

Tags: global, extern, multiple-instances

I want to access a variable in multiple `.cpp` files. I looked into several resources. I could not solve it though. I am using `cmake` to build all the codes in this project. Following is an example that exactly matches with my problem. Basically, I want `val` to print 42 in both `code1.cpp` and `code2.cpp`. When, I build these three files it complains: `undefined reference to 'he::val' collect2: error:ld returned 1 exit status` for both the .cpp files.

> header1.h

```
#ifndef HEADER1_H
#define HEADER1_H
#include <iostream>
namespace he {
extern int val;
}
#endif // HEADER1_H
```

> code1.cpp

```
#include "header1.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace he;

int func()
{
std::cout << val << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
val=20;
func();
return 0;
}
```

> code2.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "header1.h"
using namespace he;

int main()
{
std::cout << val << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
extern int val;
```

Is a variable declaration. You need, somewhere (in one of your cpp files), to define the variable:

```
int val;
```

Actually, since you have two main() functions, these are two separate programs. Then your variable definition needs to be in both, like this:

```
namespace he {
    int val;
}
```

But your extern declaration in the header file makes your variable global, which is usually frowned upon. It all depends, of course on what your purpose is.

Also, since two main() functions mean two separate programs, there is no variable sharing.

Comment: Then how can I share variable? Is there any other alternative way?

Comment: To share a variable between two cpp files, you define it in one, and declare it as extern in the other (most often via a header file). But best practice is to encapsulate data in modules, and to offer access through functions, or methods, not by allowing direct access to variables.

Comment: Hi, I searched a lot and found `boost::shared_memory_object` to be useful. But then, when I try to build a simple program in https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.interprocess-managed-shared-memory  (example 33.6), I get following error.   `In function boost::interprocess::shared_memory_object::priv_open_or_create(boost::interprocess::ipcdetail::create_enum_t, char const*, boost::interprocess::mode_t, boost::interprocess::permissions const&)':` It also shows undefined refernce to `shm_open`, `shm_unlink`.

Comment: You probably need to add some libraries to your linkage, which of course implies that they prior to that need to have been installed on your system. Check the boost documentation for the installation and the CMake manual for the inclusion of libraries.